# mongoose.Schema for IoT Data Array and fetch the data to chart.js

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, chart.js, mongoose-schema

first I need a mongoose.Schema for the iotdata which containts:

1. device id
2. entity type
3. timestamp
4. attributes has a key and a value such as *"key": "temperature" and "value": 12*

I wrote this array but I am not sure, If it is correctly:

```
const DataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    device_id:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    entity_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    time: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    
    attributes:  { type : Array , "default" : []}

});
```

Next line:

```
const Data = module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);
```

After that I want to fetch the data to chart.js
The frontend is written in Angular.
I created a service component in Angular to connect to the backend Node.js Express:

```
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Array<Data> = [];
  data: Data;
  device_id: string;
  entity_type: string;
time: date, 
attributes: array

   
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.DataService.getData().subscribe(
      (data: any) => // set response type to any
      {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(this.data);
      }
    );

  }

}
```

but how can I fetch the data to the chart.j?

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,  **-> The data here should be the data from the mongodb**
    options: options
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model creation id correct,

You need to Create Controller files and Routes for getting data in Node JS, Post to that you will be able to get data . Kindly let me know any more help required